# Including crop marks when printing

Tags: printing, crop

I would like to print crop marks around my document (an invitation). The invitation has a smaller size than the physical paper and the crop marks aid in the cutting process. Using the [`crop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/crop) package, here is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvips=false,pdftex=false,vtex=false,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in,margin=0.25in,bottom=1in,top=1in,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[letter,pdflatex,landscape,center]{crop}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}%
\crop[cam]
\centering

{\Huge Example Invitation}\\[1.5 in]

\begin{Large}
Date\\%
\&\\%
Time\\
\end{Large}\vspace{0.5in}

{\large Location}
\end{document}
```

Since the invitation itself is only 4x6 in, I should be able print two invitations on each letter-sized piece of paper. The crop package has a `mount2` option, but I was not able to get it to work. Has anyone ever done this?

Comment: The `mount2` option isn't designed for placing multiple logical pages on one physical sheet of paper, it only suppresses the inner crop marks - the process of assembling the pages is left to you, which can be done as shown in [Harish Kumar's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49971/3323). Unfortunately, this fact isn't stated very cleary in the [`crop` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/crop).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `pdfpages`. package for this. First produce a pdf file of your invitations (with tight border) (I used snip tool and took a screen shot. Hence quality is not very good.). Then you can include them in another file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=0.2in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\includepdf [pages=-,booklet,landscape]{capture.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, `pdfpages` ended up being useful, but I had to do the following:  
    \includepdf[pages={1,1},nup=1x2,landscape,noautoscale]{test.pdf}

This inserts the invitation image (test.pdf) twice on the same page and does not rescale anything. In generating the invitation image, I had to make the physical paper size smaller so that the multiple copies would fit on the final physical sheet, while still showing a portion of the crop marks, i.e.:
    \usepackage[pdflatex,center,cam,height=7in,width=5in]{crop}