# Print <A4 at 100%

Tags: printing, crop

What LaTeX package is best used to show crop marks on a page, so that I can print a LaTeX pdf page on an A4 sheet of paper at 100% in order to check the physical font size display. In doing so, I don't want the pdf page enlarged or reduced. What is the best way to do this? 
Best practice?

Comment: You have to check the settings of your pdf-viewer (if you print from a viewer), of the printing command and of the printer to make sure that the size is not modified. LaTeX has nothing to do with it; it depends on the tool chain that handles the pdf afterwards.

Comment: latex will not scale so you just need to print the pdf at its default size using whatever method you use to print.

Comment: @gernot: Crop marks is a Latex issue. David Carlisle: what tools give the best results?

Comment: If you are interested in crop marks in LaTeX, just search for "latex crop marks", and you will find examples using packages like `pdfpages` or `crop`. For the rest of your questions, make a test print with lines of some known length and check whether they are distorted. If yes, you have to go through the options of your tool(s) and set everything to non-modifying (the options have different names). Hard to give specific advice, as it depends on operating system, tools, printing device ...

Comment: For cropmarks you can use the `crop` package.

Comment: @gernot oh so it does:-)

Comment: Question, as it is now rephrased, falls within the scope of this site (imho). However, if you only need to print the document at its actual size, I don't think crop marks are needed. Anyway, that's not the question anymore.

Comment: @ebo The crop mark part has been answered in the comments. The question reopened would become a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49968/including-crop-marks-when-printing or some other posting. A relevant new question might be something like "Using the crop or the pdfpages package, how can I change the crop marks to ...?" The rest regarding undistorted printing has also been addressed in the comments and is outside of LaTeX.

Comment: @gernot I do agree, but I think closing it because of as duplicate would be more appropriate.

Comment: @ebo Therefore I have voted for reopen ;-)